# Mongoose / MongoDB merging two find queries

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I know this will be a simple answer but I've never had to do more than a single query at a time before!

I have a game item, and I want to return the games a user is part of as a list, it queries first to see if they're host, and then if they're a player. Then taking the result of both of those queries and sorting by createdOn time.

As you'll see, I have it working for the first query for gamePlayers.user, but I need to also be able to query host.user.

Like I said, I know this will have a simple answer but my googling is coming up empty and I'd appreciate any responses!

```
router.get('/currentgames', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
(req, res) => {

    const errors = {};
    const userId = req.user.id;

    Game.find({"gamePlayers.user": userId})
        .limit(10)
        .sort({lastUpdated: -1})
        .then(games => {
          if(!games) {
            errors.nousergames = 'You have no games yet';
            return res.status(204).json(errors);
          }
            res.json(games);
        })
        .catch(err =>
          res.status(404).json({ game: 'There are no games'})
        );
  });
```

Comment: Is `host.user` in another schema?

Comment: Wrap both queries into Promise.all and return both lists into sorting function. Then create response. You can write `Promise.all([firstquery, secondquery]).then(results => sortByCreateOn(results))`. sortByCreateOn function should include res.json(result)..

Comment: @ToanTran not in a different schema, just a diff area of the object within the array.

Comment: @bigless I'll give that a go :)

Comment: @bigless I'm having no luck with that layout, and I'm guessing it's because I am doing something wrong. Is there any chance you could write out a snippet to explain? I'd be so appreciative.

Comment: Can you provide code and error you are facing?